# Does Majora's Mask (Nintendo 64) actually have real-time calculation of the Deku bubble "mirror world"?

Tags: nintendo-64

If you, in the Deku scrub shape, walk up to Tingle hanging from his balloon in the air, enter first-person view and blow up a bubble which you shoot away at him, the resulting bubble shape/object will have reflections of Tingle's bubble in it.

I've noticed this many times in other situations, but I witnessed the above scene earlier today when I was watching a live stream of this game. Sadly, I was unable to "rewind" it to take a screenshot. It would've been nice to get an image to show exactly what I mean.

Anyway, what I wonder is whether this semi-transparent "bubble" actually calculates the entire 3D world and its objects to determine what kind of reflection to draw as a reflection on the bubble object, or if it's somehow "trick-filmed", such as only including specific objects and/or maybe "pre-calculating" it in some way, giving the *illusion* that it actually reflects the entire 3D environment when it really doesn't do that at all?

One of the things that make the Nintendo 64 so interesting is that it both has a very capable and advanced ability to draw realtime 3D environments, and also some seriously limiting hardware if you consider the expectations at this point.

Yes, I'm aware that Majora's Mask is one of the N64 games which *required* the Expansion Pak (+4 MB RAM, for a total of 8 MB) to run at all. But simply having more RAM might not matter in terms of doing this (presumably) very CPU-expensive calculation.

Comment: "will have reflections of Tingle's bubble in it" - do you mean Tingle's balloon, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Not an answer, but it may be helpful that, when it comes to 3D rendering, RAM is often more of a bottleneck than computing power. Scenes do need several comparable large data sets that have to be direct accessible all the time. Graphic card performance is quite limited it cant be held in card memory but needs to be transferred from main memory. That's the main reason card memory is now several magnitudes larger than the picture it generates. A 4k frame is only about 24 MiB, but you'll need 100 to 1000 times the RAM to hold object and texture data. The problem was already the same back then.

Comment: I strongly suspect it was just coincidence, like a green object behind the bubble.